# Kotlin function "collapse all" in IntelliJ / Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin, keyboard-shortcuts

For Java classes IntellliJ/ Android Studio's "collapse all" keyboard shortcut collapses just methods:

[image]

However the same is not true for Kotlin classes. Instead the whole class is collapsed. Before I report this as a bug, is there a known flag/workaround/setting? I don't see a way in IntelliJ/AndroidStudio preferences to change what "collapse all" actually collapses

[image]

========================

UPDATE:

Multiple methods, testing different cursor locations.

Java:

[image]

Kotlin:

[image]

Comment: Must needed features for android developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Folding regions are implemented differently depending on the language.

As you can see, there is no folding region for the **Java** class in the left editor gutter.

On the other hand, **Kotlin** has folding regions defined for the classes.

It's not a bug, but a difference in the implementation and there is no setting to control this behavior. A request is welcome in [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) in case you feel it should be improved.

Comment: Done https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-228403 thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The keyboard shortcut depends on the scope your cursor is in. In the first gif, your cursor is within the scope of the method, so the keyboard shortcut collapses the method. But in the second gif, your cursor is outside the scope of any method, but within the scope of the class, so the class is collapsed.

Comment: I admit it's impossible to tell from my screenshots but i'm using the "collapse all" keyboard shortcut, not the "collapse" one. If I reproduce the above example w/ two methods in each class and try w/ cursor in different locations then collapse all stil.collapses all methods in java file but collapses entire class in kotlin file.

Answer (score 1):

## Collapse all methods in Kotlin

While in Java file it is enough just to press CTRL, SHIFT and - ,
if you want to collapse all methods in a **Kotlin** file in **IntelliJ** there is a way that can help you do it easily.

Initial state:

```
class Person {
    private fun methodA() {
        //method body
    }
    private fun methodB() {
        //method body
    }
    private fun methodC() {
        //method body
    }
}
```

Press at the same time **CTRL**, **SHIFT** and **-**

You will get:

```
class Person {...}
```

And now with the cursor press inside the three dots {...}

You will get:

```
class Person {
    private fun methodA() {...}
    private fun methodB() {...}
    private fun methodC() {...}
}
```

This is a lot easier than collapsing each method, especially when you have hundreds of methods in a Kotlin file.

Answer (score 0):

**Super Future**

**## Just Press CTRL + SHIFT + -**

 ( CTRL and SHIFT and - )

[image]

**And**

**## Just Press for expand CTRL + SHIFT + +**

 ( CTRL and SHIFT and + )